# Keep submenu open on mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation, mouseover

A navigation menu I'm working on has a default CSS behavior (for those rare people who have JavaScript disabled). By default, the submenu is not displayed:

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
display:none;
}
```

On hover, the submenu is revealed:

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block;  
}
```

For the JavaScript-minded majority, the menu is juiced up with the following jQuery snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/* cancel the default CSS hover behavior */

 $('.main-navigation ul li').on('mouseover',function(){
        $('.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
     });

/* toggle submenu display (if the submenu actually exists) */

   $('.main-navigation ul li a').click(function() { 
    var li = $(this).closest('li'); 
    if(li.has('ul')) li.find('ul').slideToggle(100); 
});

});
```

This toggling works great, except it only works as long as the mouse cursor stays over the parent link. If the submenu is open, and the user happens to move the mouse away from the parent link, the submenu snaps shut.

**Question:** How do I keep the submenu open on mouse out, if it's been already open?

I tried adding something like this to my jQuery snippet:

```
$('.main-navigation ul li').on('mouseout',function(){
    if ($('.main-navigation ul li ul').css('display') = 'none') {
    $('.main-navigation ul li ul').css('display', 'none');
} else if ($('.main-navigation ul li ul').css('display') = 'block') {
    $('.main-navigation ul li ul').css('display', 'block');
}
});
```

Not only it's mediocre coding, but it also actually doesn't work. ;-(

How should I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure the click issue yet (looking at it), but you don't need JavaScript to "disable" the CSS. Simply use `<noscript>` tags, like so:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .exampleclass:hover { display: block; }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

Or you could simply add a `no-js` class to you main menu element, then remove that class if JS is enabled at the very start of your JavaScript. Then write your "no-js css" to use `.no-js` + whatever children instead of the main class.

### UPDATE

The problem is simple, when you use `mouseover` to cancel your "non-js" css, the menu is still being hidden everytime the user hovers over that submenu. In other words, you're not just removing the "no js" css, you're hiding it on every mouseover of `.main-navigation ul li`!

Simply follow something in my first suggestion, then **remove** the mouseover function completely and *viola*! problem solved!

I wrote a jsFiddle using your code to show how I might approach it.

## jsFiddle

### Code

```
$(function() {
    //    See in css where i changed `.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul` to `.main-navigation.no-js ul li:hover > ul`
    //    See Also in HTML where i added class `no-js` to `#site-navigation`
    $(".no-js").removeClass("no-js");
    $('.main-navigation ul li a').on("click", function(e) {
        //    first hide sibling sub-menus!
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().each(function(i) { $(this).find("ul").slideUp("fast"); });
        //    no need for the if statement you had. 
        //    jQuery is "smart", if it doesn't exist, 
        //        then this function simply won't do anything!
        $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(100); 
    })
    //    and just to add a little for ya, 
    //        the following will slideUp our submenu if user hovers away from MAIN MENU
    .closest("ul").on("mouseleave", function(e) {
        $(this).find("ul:visible").slideUp("slow");
    });
})
```

Step-by-Step

1. Where you have manual script at between `<script type="text/javascript">` tags, just before that `noscript` tage you threw in(which you can remove), replace all your JS with the following:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

           jQuery(".no-js").removeClass("no-js");
           jQuery('.main-navigation ul li a').on("click", function(e) {
               $(this).closest('li').siblings().each(function(i) { $(this).find("ul").slideUp("fast"); });
               jQuery(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(100); 
           })
           //  If you find the menu hiding to fast, simply remove or comment out the next 3 lines
           jQuery('.main-navigation ul').on("mouseleave", function(e) {
               jQuery(this).find("ul:visible").slideUp("slow");
           });

       });
   </script>
   ```
2. Remove the `NOSCRIPT` TAGS
3. In your CSS Code:

   ```
   /* Find the area that was written as */
   .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
       display:block;  
   }

   /* And replace it with the following */
   .main-navigation.no-js ul li:hover > ul {
       display:block;  
   }
   ```
4. Finally, look in your HTML, find the line written as `<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">` and replace it with:

   ```
   <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation no-js" role="navigation">
   ```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you @SpYk3HH. Would appreciate your take on the main issue, too.

Comment: as i mentioned, looking it over now

Comment: Actually, I think what you're suggesting should solve the main issue, too, @SpYk3HH. Trying now... Tried it. Nope, the issue persists.

Comment: @Figaro ANSWER UPDATED AND SOLUTION FOUND

Comment: Let me try that, @SpYk3HH – thank you. I'm not sure if I understand the last bit about sliding up on mouselieave – what does it do?

Comment: @Figaro The last bit is just an "extra" i added that will "hide a submenu" if the user hover away from the "whole menu area". I used jQuery's "chainging" to make the call with `.closest("ul")` since the last element object returned is `.main-navigation ul li a`, this will get the main menu `ul`. Tho you could call it directly with something like `$("#menu-main-menu").on("mouseleave" ...`

Comment: @Figaro, the last "xtra" i threw in may need adjusted according to your layout, but hard for me to test on your page with al your other functions. remember to remove all previous javascript calls to this action before adding the new fix

Comment: A silly question, @SpYk3HH – am I adding the .no-js class correctly: class="main-navigation no-js" – ?

Comment: yes, and make the appropriate change in CSS, I'll update my answer with step by step instructions based on what I see of your page

Comment: Okay, @SpYk3HH, I updated my CSS and replaced my original snippet with the one you created. So far the problem is still there – could you please tale a look?

Comment: I take it back, @SpYk3HH, looks like it is working. Checking a couple of things...

Comment: Perfect, @SpYk3HH, you're the best, thank you! There's one more issue with the page though, but it probably deserves a separate question. Could you try clicking once on ABOUT and then clicking on INVESTORS?

Comment: @Figaro oh yea, my bad, i forgot to hide previously opened menues, i'll fix my code and change it in answer, gimmie just a minute

Comment: @Figaro Fixed issue by adding `$(this).closest('li').siblings().each(function(i) { $(this).find("ul").slideUp("fast"); });` as the ***FIRST*** line of our "**click**" function! See updated answer for more info

Comment: Thank you, @SpYk3HH, you've single-hanmdedly saved me from a major nervous breakdown.

Comment: Actually, @SpYk3HH - would you have time for taking a look at another question, about the same site and related in subject matter to the one you just helped me solve? I'd be truly grateful!

Comment: @Figaro sure, you can post it as another question or you could make an [SO Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and we could talk it over there, just gimmie a few mins to do some stuff

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30356/discussion-between-figaro-and-spyk3hh)

Answer (score 1):

so here is where IE did something neat, and jquery makes it browser agnostic so it's usable.  mouseleave is 'mouseout' for the selected element and any of its subelements in IE, and jquery makes it work for the other browsers.

> The mouseleave JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer.
>   Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so
>   that it can be used regardless of browser. This event is sent to an
>   element when the mouse pointer leaves the element. Any HTML element
>   can receive this event.

mouseover - when someone mouses over the 'parent' ul li you want to show any sub uls

click - when someone clicks the parent ul li you want to hide or show any sub uls

[mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) - IE specific that jquery makes browser agnostic for you.

leave the menus in a working state using `<noscript>` tags, and intend the javascript to go from there if it is available.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfygrvty/gdA3f/)  -- this fiddle is just to give you a start, as i didn't put in any of your css.

```
$(function () {
    $("ul").on({"mouseover":function(event){
        $(this).find("ul").show("slow");
    }},"li.menu-item",null).on({"click":function(event){
        $(this).find("ul").toggle("slow");
    }},null,null).on({"mouseleave":function(event){
        $(this).find("ul").hide("slow");
    }},null,null);
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not quite sure what you mean by these things, @DefyGravity. Maybe you could rephrase or expand?

Comment: @SpYk3HH you caught me quoting jquery documentation.

Comment: looks like spyke really wants this answer ;)  all his.  the big thing is switching to `mouseleave` to handle the correct mouse behavior.