# Keep sub menu open on mouse out if sub option clicked/selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp

Having a side menu with parent and child options which used to display the content on the right main div if any of the child options are selected. Parent options will be shown on page load and
when the mouse hovers on the parent, child options are displayed, and when the mouse out the child options are hiding.

Now I wanted to keep the child options(submenu) expanded of that particular parent on mouse out also if the child option is selected/clicked and it should be hidden when other parent-child options are selected.

Below is the CSS property

```
# parent
 ul li: hover li{
    display : block;
  } 
# child
ul li ul li a : hover{
  background-color - red;
  border-radious: 25px;
  color : red;
   }
```

[Keep submenu open on mouse out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675991/keep-submenu-open-on-mouse-out), already tried this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed **mouseover event** to a **mouse-click event**, and then by using jquery I fulfilled my requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  
   #To prevent action on child click
   if(e.target !==e.currentTarget)
     return ;

  $("li.parent").children().addClass("dropdown")
 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a class (e.g. selected/active) to the parent, if the child option is selected/clicked, and using that class to make the child 'display block important' might help you in this situation.

Try this.

**CODE**

```
//JS
$('.child-option').on('click', function() {
    $('.child-option').parents('.parent').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parents('.parent').addClass('selected');
});


//CSS
.parent.selected li {
    display: block!important;
}
```